# Unity: build and run for Android is unavialable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, configure

My Unity IDE doesn't allow me to run the project for Android. I successfully do it for iOS, but the android section is totally disabled.
What am I missing?
I use AndroidSDK with both Android Studio and Eclipse - they normally build native projects and run them on devices and emulators. So, there must not be a problem with Android SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unable-to-select-android-platform.372097/).  "*Unity 5.3 only has a few platforms downloaded and installed by default. In the installer, you need to check the platforms you need.*"
When you install unity, make sure you check these

[image: Unity download assistant screenshot]

Comment: yeah, it looks like this is it. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to install Android module separately now

Comment: I think that you can run the installer again and install only the missing component. Keep us up to date  :)

Comment: that's exactly I had to do, since all separate installers were not compatible with my current Unity version. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, this will happen with Unity Hub even though you already installed the Android module. What's happening is Unity Hub is putting the files in the wrong place. It's putting the files where Unity Hub is installed, instead of in the correct Unity engine subfolder.

1. Find where you put the `UnityHub.appimage` binary.
2. In that folder you will see a lot of extra files that weren't there before.  Those are the Android module files that were incorrectly placed in that folder. Sorting the files/folders by date modified, may help you find the right ones. Some examples of these folders and files:

   /Apk

   /Data

   /Source

   /Tools

   /Variations

   /Whitelists

   ivy.xml

   modules.asset

   UnityEditor.Android.Extensions.dll

4. Copy or Cut all of those folders and files.
5. Find where your Unity engine install folder is located. You can quickly find this in Unity Hub by going to Installs > click the 3 dots > "Show in File Browser". Make sure you're clicking on the engine you're using for this project.
   [image]
6. Navigate to "202#.#.### > Editor > Data > PlaybackEngines > AndroidPlayer".
7. Paste the folders and files here.
8. After restarting the Unity editor, going to "File > Build Settings..", you should now see config settings in the Android tab.
   [image]

This answer was first discovered on the Unity forum, since it helped me I'm sharing here as well. http://answers.unity.com/answers/1749552/view.html

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Android module. You failed to include it while installing Unity so you have to do it [separately](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta). Make sure the version matches with the Unity version you have.

[image]

Comment: I cant' figure out, how to install component separately? I forgot to mention, I'm on Mac

Comment: @DeepThought Go on the link I mentioned. Click Mac Component Installers instead of Windows. Select Android like circled in the picture then download it. Close Unity then run the new downloaded exe program. What Unity version did you install? I want to make sure I link you to the correct version.

Comment: finally I had to install whole unity latest version cause all components I tried were not compatible with my current unity version (3.2.1f1). thanks for your solution, I'm going to check Haim Bendanan's answer as correct to support his beginning in SO life, if you don't mind)

Comment: @DeepThought That's fine. It doesn't matter which answer you chose as long as it solved your problem. I can't believe people are still using 3.2.1f1. This is more than 5 years old.... I bet it wont work on the the latest iOS devices.

Comment: that's strange, I've downloaded it on January 2016 from official Unity web site.

Comment: @DeepThought Check the version by opening the program and going to Help->About Unity. Is it 5.3.2.1f1 or just 3.2.1f1?

Comment: Now it shows 5.4.0b18 since I've completely reinstalled Unity

Comment: @DeepThought You are fine now. You went with the link the I posted and you now have the latest version. I chocked when I saw 3.2.1f1. That's like using Windows 95 in 2016. Anyways, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had a up and running Unity editor in my mac. I had been using it couple of months to develop android apps. Suddenly it says **No Android Module Loaded**. I simply just restarted my machine, now it works again!